# If statement to get different attributes - fetchXML

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

Using SQL as example, is it possible to have a "if select" statement in FetchXML to get different attributes depending on a condition?

For example, if @value=1 , fetch attributes "a" and "b", else, fetch attributes "c" and "d".

I am new to this.

Comment: Are you using fetchxml in SSRS report or js/C# coding? Can you write the sql equivalent of fetchxml you are looking for?

Comment: Neither. I am using it in another not so famous software. The equivalent would be something like: if @value=1 select column_a, column_b from {source} else select column_c, column_d from {source}.  -- @value is a variable I can access and declare in the software, the source is a lookuptable in the sql version, turned into an entity in Dynamics. Each column corresponds to an attribute in Dynamics.

Comment: Pls edit the question & add the details, it’s hard to read in comments..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever it is, SQL or fetchXML in js/C# or any other technology/software, the only way to achieve this requirement is - Dynamic query technique. Compose the query in string the way we want & execute the string query in runtime.

For example:

```
string query =  @"
   <fetch mapping='logical'>
     <entity name='contact'>";

if (value == 1)
{
        query+= "<attribute name='title'/> 
                 <attribute name='fullname'/>";
}
else
{
        query+= "<attribute name='firstname'/> 
                 <attribute name='lastname'/>";
}

     query+= "</entity> 
            </fetch>";
```